# Secure Form Submission

Tags: security, websites, codeigniter, https

This is probably a no brainer, but I've not been able to find an answer that is definitive.

I have a Codeigniter site running on Apache with mod_rewrite (to get rid of index.php) and mod_ssl for HTTPS.  My question is.....

If at https://example.com/form.php I have a form like this...

```
<form action="/process.php">
.....
</form>
```

Will that form be submitted to HTTPS, or is it going over HTTP?  Do I have to explicitly say HTTPS in the action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a link (or form action) with a relative URI (without a scheme and hostname), then the URI will be completed with the scheme and hostname of the page containing the link.

This means that, if you are on the page "https://example.com/form.php", then the link/action "/process.php" will result in a request for the URI "https://example.com/process.php".
Similarly, that link on the page "http://nowhere.example.com/form.php" will go to "http://nowhere.example.com/process.php".